# How to quantify the effect of the common mode input for a given CMRR?

Tags: operational-amplifier, cmrr

The definition of CMRR is 20×log10(Aol/Acm) where Aol is the open loop gain and Acm is the common mode gain.

If we have a buffer with 20dB CMRR opamp and if we apply 1V differential input along with 1V common mode input as shown in my hand drawn example:

[image]

In this case we dont know the open loop gain but we know the CMRR. What will be the total output voltage? In other words how to quantify the contribution of the 1V common mode input to the output voltage. We are using feedback here so would that effect CMRR?

**Edit:**

Look at a data acquisition input parameters:

[image]

CMRR is given as 92dB but Aol never mentioned. Does that mean we cannot quantify Acm?

Comment: What is the differential gain than (Aol)?

Comment: Im confused because there is feedback and the rest

Comment: https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/common-mode-voltage-for-op-amp.156819/#post-1361227

Comment: Is my buffer diagram with differential amplifier  wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. Your buffer has only one input (noninverting).

Comment: Open loop gain is not given in my question can se still calculate the Acm?

Comment: Looks like a DAQ card not an opamp?

Comment: No, you cannot find Acm without knowing the Aol. Becouse the CMRR is a ratio between differential gain and common-mode gain.

Comment: @sstobbe It is probably inAmp with buffers I mean the Daq input. But does CMRR has a different meaning in that context? They provide CMRR but not Aol. So CMRR here alone must be enough to quantify the output noise due to 1V common mode input but how?

Comment: In my original question we concluded CMRR info without Aol will not let us to calculate the output noise due to 1V common mode voltage. But for the Daq input only CMRR is given and Aol is not given in datasheet, can we calculate the output noise due to 1V common mode voltage in that case?

Comment: You can calculate it as an input referred voltage simply as (For example 10V range) 92dB below the 1V of common mode, or 112dB below full scale (as your common mode voltage is 20dB below full scale). You don't know Vol, but you don't care with the DAQ card because you know input referred full scale (Which wraps up amplifier and ADC reference in a single convenient number). I would note that that measurement is made at 60Hz, it will be MUCH lower at higher frequency.

Comment: @DanMills This is very confusing. One definition(the diff amplifier) requires open loop gain Aol and the later(DAQ input amplifier) does not. Lets ignore the frequency dependence and consider only for 60Hz. For -/+10V range how would you calculate calculate the noise for 1V common mode input?  92dB is 39811 voltage ratio. Does that mean 1V common mode input will cause +/- (1/39810)V output?

Comment: And if you can explain the wrapping part would be great. Of course if you have time and if you can write an answer. This is a bit implicit. Two CMMR are different meanings or..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMRR is at its most basic the amount by which a circuit rejects common mode input relative a differential input of the same magnitude.

Consider your DAQ card, it has a differential input which drives some doings (fet input instrumentation opamps and shit) that eventually get measured by an ADC and fed to some software that knows the scale factors so it can produce a reading in volts. You have no knowledge of the internal scale factors, on some settings it is amplifying before it hits the ADC, some settings it is probably attenuating, it don't matter. It has (in some settings) gain, but you don't know what it is, you just know what full scale range is in terms of volts per sample value and maximum input.

Now we know (providing we believe the datasheet) that at 60Hz on the +-10V scale we get a CMRR of 92dB, which means that common mode inputs (Providing they remain within the allowed range) at 60Hz will be attenuated by 92dB before they get summed in with the differential mode signal you are measuring. 92dB is (in voltage terms) a factor of about 2.5*10^-5, so 1V or common mode input will appear as about 2.5*10^-5V of noise added to the differential mode signal which in that mode has a full scale range of +-10V.

One thing about that card is that the input impedance is apparently 100G Ohms, I don't believe it, the capacitive loading will screw that massively at the top of the small signal bandwidth! But lets roll with it, it might be sufficiently true close to DC, this means that reasonably small source impedance imbalances will not seriously degrade CMRR. However source impedance may if large enough convert that couple of hundred pA of bias and offset into an annoying voltage, doubly so if it changes with temperature, metrology is a bitch like that.

Comment: But why does your first sentence not apply to the original question? Given a diff amplifier CMRR as 20dB can a 1V common mode voltage’s effect on output calculated? If we dont know open loop gain Aol, G36 says in comments we cannot calculate it.

Comment: Anyway dont bother I dont think I will ever understand this

Comment: Yes, obviously, it will add a signal 20dB below 1V to the output! So 100mV of noise with a 1V CM noise input.... With opamps you can just assume Aol is 'Large', and the maths works (Particularly at low frequency). Nobody uses opamps open loop, there is always a feedback network wrapped around them to make them reasonably behaved, and this is usually what dominates the performance.  Seriously only undergraduate textbooks sweat open loop gain, everyone else just goes 'meh, talk to me about Gain Bandwidth Product, far more useful for actual design'.

Comment: I see thanks the comments under the question made me confused now more clear.